# Laravel automatically change status in DB after date expires

Tags: php, laravel, database, eloquent

I've got the `tasks` table, this table has `status` and `deadline` columns. How can status be changed to "expired" automatically when current date will become greater than task's deadline date? Is there any realtime event listeners in Laravel?

I guess that's how event listener class should look like, but I'm not sure what to do next.

```
<?php
 
namespace App\Events;
 
use App\Models\Task;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\InteractsWithSockets;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Events\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
 
class DeadlineExpired
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;
 
    /**
     * The task instance.
     *
     * @var \App\Models\Task
     */

    public $task;
 
    /**
     * Create a new event instance.
     *
     * @param  \App\Models\Task $task
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(Task $task)
    {
        $this->task = $task;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're checking only the date. Your cron needs to run only once at midnight. Use Laravel Scheduler to do your Job.
First create a class

```
class UpdateTasks
{
    public function __invoke()
    {
        // do your task here...e.g.,
        Tasks::whereDate('deadline','<',today())->update(['status'=>'expired']);
    }
}
```

Then in your app\Console\Kernel.php, schedule method-

```
$schedule->call(new UpdateTasks())->daily();
```

Finally configure a cron job at your server to run the schedule command daily at midnight.

```
php artisan schedule:run
```

Answer (score 0):

There are Realtime event listeners but thes require a action to fire. Example are when a model is Created, Updated or Deleted then these events fire.

There is no built in "listener" to ping every model waiting for a field you defined to change.

If there is further logic you would like to fire when the Task becomes expired (like send email) then your best would be to run a check for any new expired Tasks using the scheduler.
The Scheduler runs every minute - set by cron.